# Common substrings on the internet

Tags: statistics, nlp, nltk, text-processing

Is there a way to find out the most common substrings which are not English words occuring in all the documents(more importantly html) on internet (statistically significant sample would also be good), Is it possible to get some approximations say for example "corp" could be  a candidate as its not a whole English word , but "umbrella", "the" cannot be candidates as they are themselves whole words in English.

Comment: Approach Google with this question (and some money).

Answer (score 2):

I will not judge if what you ask could be useful at all...

The answer: it is possible to bootstrap your own web-corpora and you can easily find well documented methods at [ACL SIGWAC](https://www.sigwac.org.uk/). The basic approach consists in gathering a set of representative seed words (in any language or languages) and combine them in order to get search engine hits. You then feed a web crawler the obtained urls and let the crawler fetch documents until you have enough for your purposes.

Finally, you would have to extract the raw text and compute a series of character n-gram models for all the data. What can you expect? Single characters are much more frequent than any combination longer than 1 character, combinations of two characters are more frequent than tri-grams, and so forth. I suspect it all falls under Zipf's law. However, your aim of filtering out sequences that correspond to whole words is tricky and would pose further problems.

While there might be other tools out there, I have had excellent results using a combination of the [BootCaT toolkit](http://bootcat.sslmit.unibo.it/) and the [Heritrix crawler](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix) to build large web-based corpora.

Comment: nice, I would only be interested in trigrams and above. My motivation is that such trigrams can also allow us to find search substrings that would yield maximum results.